# How to load a DOM in PHP through Google Chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, dom

I'm trying to download a DOM after JavaScript executed. This is possible from the command line:

on MaxOS:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --ignore-gpu-blocklist --headless --dump-dom --disable-gpu https://stackoverflow.com
```

This will dump the rendered DOM (after DOM-ready) to the terminal screen. I'm trying to do the same using PHP's `exec`:

```
$command = '/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --ignore-gpu-blocklist --headless --dump-dom --disable-gpu https://stackoverflow.com';
exec("$command 2>&1", $a);
var_dump($a);
```

I get an error:

```
array(2) {   
  [0]=>  string(116) "[1207/151925.277477:WARNING:angle_platform_impl.cc(49)] RendererVk.cpp:1962 (initialize): ANGLE VMA version: 2003000"    
  [1]=>  string(112) "[1207/151925.538173:ERROR:bootstrap.cc(65)] bootstrap_look_up com.apple.ReportCrash: Unknown service name (1102)" 
}
```

The warning I can ignore, but the error I can't seem to fix.

First thing I thought was permissions maybe, but I can get the version of Chrome on my machine through PHP without a problem:

```
$command = '/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --version';
exec("$command 2>&1", $a);
var_dump($a);
```

This will output:

```
array(1) { 
 [0]=> string(28) "Google Chrome 119.0.6045.199" 
}
```

How do I download the rendered DOM through Chrome in PHP?

Comment: Works for me PHP 8.2.11 NTS, Google Chrome 119.0.6045.199, 2020 i7 13" Air Ventura 13.0.1. Try to `strace` perhaps?